# Ember. How to delete a view's instance

Tags: view, ember.js

Im struggling to delete a view's instance. On view hbs i use each loop to show view hbs. On another field click i add a  "  . " to a json object, which then adds another field to the template.

```
>js>App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    anotherField: [{name: 'testname'}],

    actions: {

      moreFields: function(){
          this.get('anotherField').pushObject({name: ''});      
      },
      less: function(){
        var counter = this.get('anotherField');
        counter.shift();
        this.set('anotherField', counter);
```

And hbs

```
{{#each view.anotherField}}
        {{view Ember.TextField}}
 {{/each}}
    <button {{action 'moreFields' target='view'}}> ++ </button>
    <button {{action 'less' target='view'}}> -- </button>
```

http://jsbin.com/iSUdiCaX/17/edit

Cheers

Kristjan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `shift` method Ember doesn't get notified that the `anotherField` property changed, and therefore it doesn't update the template. You can check this by adding `this.rerender()` at the end of the `less` action.

You could:

1. call `this.propertyDidChange('anotherField')` to notify the property changed: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_propertyDidChange
2. use the `slice` method: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_slice

   ```
   var sliced = this.get('anotherField').slice(0, this.get('anotherField').length - 1);
   this.set('anotherField' sliced);
   ```

I also noticed you're using the View to handle the actions whereas I believe the Controller would be a better place to do so.

**EDIT**
Well it depends.... I believe the controllers are a good place because they have knowledge of the model (the view also has it via the **controller**). if your `anotherField` property is only needed for displaying or event handling logic then I believe it is a good idea to leave it in the `view`. from docs

> Views in Ember.js are typically only created for the following
>   reasons:
>
> When you need sophisticated handling of user events
>
> When you want to create a re-usable component

But if instead the `anotherField` property is used the held application state (user selections, needed for computed properties or other actions) then I believe it's better placed inside the controller (and therefore the actions modifying it).

Have in mind your view can handle one part of the action and send it to the controller:

```
actions: {
    something: function() {
        ..... 
        this.get('controller').send('something')   // calls send action in controller              
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thx for the answer ! =) Why do u reckon using controller is better ?